# Bootstrap datetimepicker is not visible when overflow is set

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

So I have a website, where user can set a date and time. I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker in my small fixed popup. It has much more settings so I put there `overflow-y: auto` and scroll bar should appear. It is working, but datetimepicker is not fully visible and I cant set a date, but this happens only when `overflow-y: auto` is set. CSS for that popup:

```
.test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(125, 0, 0, 0.7);
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here is **[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eoxkev9r/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Make `overflow-y: visible;`

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eoxkev9r/1/)

```
var datePickerOptions = {
    sideBySide: true,
    allowInputToggle: true,
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
    toolbarPlacement: 'top',
    showTodayButton: true,
    showClear: true,
    showClose: true,
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-time',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
        today: 'fa fa-bullseye',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-times'
    }
};

$(function() {
    $('.input-group.datetime').datetimepicker(datePickerOptions);
});
```

```css
.test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(125, 0, 0, 0.7);
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="test">
    <div class="input-group datetime">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        <input type="text" name="deadline" class="form-control" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helping me, since I need a scroll bar in that popup and `overflow-y: visible;` will destroy it.